# Showing divergence or convergence, what is enough? ex $\sum_{30}^\infty \frac{n^2}{(n^3+5)^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{30}^\infty \frac{n^2}{(n^3+5n)^2}$$

For example I have something like this can I just claim that only the leading terms matter and then show that I have $\frac{1}{n^4}$ or whatever and use the p series test or do I have to investigate the value of 5n? What is it was $5n^2?$ Would it matter at all since it only increases the amount of convergance? What if the numerator had more terms of a lesser degree? What if I had a subtraction of a lesser degree term on the bottom?

The logic I see behind it is that only the highest degree terms matter as you approach infinity so it should be permissible to drop the lesser degree terms for a comparison to prove convergence or divergence.

Comment: That's correct (only the leading terms matter); but you should probably use a comparison test anyway to be rigorous.  Use the Limit Comparison Test, e.g., here with $\sum 1/n^4$.

Comment: My book said to use the comparison test, when would I use the limit comparison test instead of the comparison test?

Comment: For the series you have above, the regular Comparison Test would be quickest. See lab's answer below. In general though, it may be slightly messy to use the regular Comparison Test. For example with $\sum \textstyle{n^2-9n\over n^3 +1}$, you can't compare directly with $\sum {1\over n}$. (It's not true that $  {n^2-9n\over n^3+1}\ge {1\over n}$). But, the Limit Comparison test will work nicely here, as with all problems of this type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just note that,

$$ \frac{n^2}{(n^3+5n)^2} \sim \frac{n^2}{(n^3)^2} =\frac{1}{n^4}. $$

Now, you can make the comparison test.

Comment: Why the comparison test when the p series seems to be more straighforward at this point?

Comment: He's *comparing* it to a $p$-series. :)

Comment: Then why use a comparison test?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

As $n>0$

$$\frac{n^2}{(n^3+5n)^2}=\frac1{(n^2+5)^2}$$

and $$\frac1{(n^2+5)^2}<\frac1{(n^2)^2}=\frac1{n^4}$$ which is a $p$ is Series with $p=4>1$

Comment: My only problem with this is that it seems like nearly all of these problems can be reduced into a p series test.

Comment: Two answers are almost same.